# menu bar child menu is hiding under javascript slider

Tags: html, css

```
* {
font-family:verdana;
font-size:12px;
line-height:16px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}

body {
background-color:#609fdf;
color:#4d4c4c;
padding:40px 0;
}

#main {
width:1085px;
}

#main_container {
background:url(img/background.png) repeat-y;
}

#content {
background:url(img/content.gif) repeat-x #c9cbcc;
min-height:470px;
margin:0 34px;
padding:20px;
}

#content_top {
background:url(img/background_top.png);
height:47px;
}

#content_bottom {
background:url(img/background_bottom.png);
height:40px;
}

.right {
float:right;
}

.left {
float:left;
}

.center {
text-align:center;
}

.clear {
clear:both;
}

.mar-t {
margin-top:10px;
}

.mar-b {
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#header {
margin-left:35px;
margin-bottom:21px;
}

#header_menu {
width:1015px;
text-align:center;
float:right;
position:relative;
right:32px;
top:-27px;
margin-right:2px;
}

#header_menu a {
color:#fff;
font-size:14px;
line-height:40px;
}

#header_menu ul {
float:right;
z-index:10;
}

#header_menu ul ul {
display:none;
border-left:1px solid #940e0f;
width:200px;
border:1px solid #940e0f;
position:absolute;
}

#header_menu li {
float:left;
background:url(http://edutube.in/word4/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/navbarLeft.png) left top no-repeat;
margin-left:5px;
}

#header_menu li a {
display:block;
background:url(http://edutube.in/word4/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/navbarRight.png) right top no-repeat;
margin-left:10px;
padding:0 15px 7px 4px;
}

#header_menu li.current_page_item {
background:url(http://edutube.in/word4/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/navbarLeft.png) no-repeat 0 -47px;
}

#header_menu li.current_page_item a {
background:url(http://edutube.in/word4/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/navbarRight.png) no-repeat right -47px;
}

#header_menu li:hover ul {
display:block;
}

#header_menu li:hover ul ul {
display:none;
}

#header_menu li:hover {
position:relative;
}

#header_menu li li {
float:none;
background:#fff;
text-align:left;
border-bottom:1px solid #940e0f;
position:relative;
margin:0;
padding:5px 5px 0 0;
}

#header_menu li li:last-child {
border-bottom:none;
}
```

and now my problem is that the side bar i need it to be over the slider (nivoslider which i am using) so that the side will be on the top of the slider and the slider will be as usual
the z-index i have tried  is not working so what is the solution for this
link of the site is below

[link](http://edutube.in/word4/)

Comment: on the z-index parts, have you also added the css position:relative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding something like the following to your CSS should make the menu list over the slider :

```
#left
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

For the z-index property to work, you need to have `position: relative` or `position: absolute` on your element.

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap the flash movie in a DIV that has a higher z-index than the menu
- Set the parameter wmode="opaque" on your embed code, this is most likely the issue